# Symfony Console command : The token storage contains no authentication token

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to launch my custom made Symfony command using php bin/console
I get this bizarre error :

> [Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException]
>
> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL

Its seem that the line responsible is

```
$user = $em->getRepository('CoreUserBundle:User')->findOneById($deck['user_id']);
            if ($user != null)
            {
                $deck_entity = new Deck();
                $deck_entity->SetId($deck['id']);
                $deck_entity->SetUser($user);
                $deck_entity->SetTitle($deck['titre']);
                $deck_entity->SetClass($deck['classe']);
                $deck_entity->SetStyle("None");
                $deck_entity->SetContentHtml($deck['contenu_html']);
                if (isset($deck['contenu_bbcode']))
                    $deck_entity->SetContentBBCode($deck['contenu_bbcode']);
                $deck_entity->SetVideo($deck['video']);
                $deck_entity->SetVersion($deck['version']);
                $deck_entity->SetIsUpdated($deck['a_jour']);
                $deck_entity->SetCraftCost($deck['craft_cout']);
                $deck_entity->SetCreationDate(new \DateTime($deck['creation']));
                $deck_entity->SetEditionDate(new \DateTime($deck['edition']));
                $deck_entity->SetDeckType($deck['deck_type']);


                $em->persist($deck_entity);

                $metadata = $em->getClassMetaData(get_class($deck_entity));
                $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
            }
```

**UPDATE :** Its seem that the error happen at the moment of persisting the entity Deck().

My firewall security are

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:  ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            remember_me:   true
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook: /login/check-facebook
                google: /login/check-google
            login_path: /login
            failure_path: /login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: core.user.user_provider
        remember_me:
            secret:    "%secret%"
            name:      f1e56d001
            lifetime:  604800
            httponly:  true
            domain:    xxxx.eu
        logout:
            path:    fos_user_security_logout
            handlers: ['sonata.page.cms_manager_selector']
            target:  /
        anonymous:  true
        switch_user:
            role:       ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
            parameter:  connect_as
```

I don't understand what I am supposed to, the error seem to tell me that i'm not authenticated, but how since I am using the console ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post what the repository class for `CoreUserBundle:User` looks like? Also, perhaps a bigger stack trace of your error, if possible!

Comment: Please, provide more code from your command. I don't think it's caused by the User repository.

Comment: The command line do not give me a biggest stack trace, this is the only line its output, I unfortunately have no idea how to ask him to provide more information. I have updated the question with more code

Answer (score 0):

after more research, its appear my Deck() entity was triggering a PostPersist event made to create a new thread from the FosCommentBundle, which apparently needed to have the currently logged user to process some stuff (which couldn't get because of the command being a console command ), I could fix the problem by bypassing these event.